# Tag CloudFormation and underlying resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template in which I have to tag every resource seperately. Can I provide tags to the stack and all underlying resources which can have tags automatically (without creating a nested stack)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS cloud formation Template- providing Tags for the stack in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513145/aws-cloud-formation-template-providing-tags-for-the-stack-in-the-template)

Answer (score 0):

The following tags automatically added by cloudformation

- aws:cloudformation:logical-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-name

Most resources that support Tags, have a property in their Cloudformation snippet to support Tags.

Some resources also have a PropogateAtLaunch like LaunchConfigurations.  [More information from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html)

What were you trying to achieve?  Better view for Cost Center, AWS Console, AWS CLI or something else